# What is the difference between int* ptr and int *ptr in C?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax, variable-declaration

I am fairly new at C and I don't know the difference between the following two variable declarations:

```
int* ptr;
int *ptr;
```

I think that in the declaration `int* ptr;`, `ptr`'s value cannot be changed whereas it can be changed for the declaration, `int *ptr;`

I am not sure if that is it though.

What is the concept behind the two declarations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C: is there a difference between "int\* fooBar;" and "int \*fooBar;"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093459/c-is-there-a-difference-between-int-foobar-and-int-foobar) and [Difference between int \*i and int\* i](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770187/difference-between-int-i-and-int-i), [Difference between int\* p and int \*p declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590150/difference-between-int-p-and-int-p-declaration) along with at least a dozen others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770187/difference-between-int-i-and-int-i

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To the compiler, there is no difference between the two declarations.

To the human reader, the former may imply that the "int*" type applies to all declarations in the same statement. However, the * binds only to the following identifier.

For example, both of the following statements declare only one pointer.

```
int* ptr, foo, bar;
int *ptr, foo, bar;
```

This statement declares multiple pointers, which prevents using the "int*" spacing.

```
int *ptr1, *ptr2, *ptr3;
```

Answer (score 4):

Spaces in C are mostly insignificant. There are occasional cases where spaces are important, but these are few and far between. The two examples you posted are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Like the others said. There is no difference. If you want to understand more complex C type declaration you could find this link userful. [Reading C declarations](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's called whitespace operator overloading, see here: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/whitespace98.pdf

Comment: I know this was posted a year ago but that link is really awesome!Thank you

Answer (score 1):

`int *p;`

```
*p
```

is no meaning for compiler, `(int*) is a type named pointer`.