# Why is the C++ variable declaration syntax inconsistent?

Tags: c++, syntax, declaration

when I declare C++ variables, I do it like this:

```
int a,b,c,d;
```

or

```
string strA,strB,strC,strD;
```

I.e., first the type then a comma separated list of variable names.

However, I declare pointers like this:

```
int *a,*b,*c,*d;
```

and references like this:

```
int &a,&b,&c,&d;
```

To be consistent it should be

```
int* a,b,c,d;
```

and

```
int& a,b,c,d;
```

Why is it not consistent?

Comment: Not sure if this is why, but one specifies the type and the other specifies how the type is referenced.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between int* ptr and int *ptr in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799561/what-is-the-difference-between-int-ptr-and-int-ptr-in-c)

Comment: Common misconception, I blame the books that teach to put the `*` or `&` next to the type and not the variable, as all learning C was thought. In short, it's from the C roots of C++.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer definitely not a dupe of that question...

Comment: It's not inconsistent. It's just not what you personally expect. Perhaps the best analogy is a car and a boat: in a car you turn the steering wheel left to go left, on a boat, you turn the rudder left to go right. Neither is any more "consistent" than the other.

Comment: @KerrekSB I would not say that. Not only the accepted answer weights in to corroborate OP's feeling, but in all other places the rest of the type systems also shows that this comma declaration grammar rule is plain wrong. it's just kept for histerical raisins. `const` applies to the type, not the variable. just like in function signature, the asterisk applies to the return type, not the function's identifier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because of the C heritage. The `*` modifier applies to the variable in C. So the C++ designers made `&` to apply to the variable as well by analogy, since they couldn't change the first without breaking C compatibility. Same is true for the array syntax too:

```
int anInt, *aPointerToInt, anArrayOfInt[100];
```

In *The Design and Evolution of C++* Bjarne Stroustrup says he wasn't happy with this but had to accept it for C compatibility. He was unhappy with this in particular:

```
int *a[10];
```

It's not clear from the declaration if `a` is a pointer to an array or an array of pointers (it's an array of pointers, you need brackets to override).

Of course, you can always use a `typedef` to clean things up a little.

Comment: +1 for quoting the source (_The Design and Evolution of C++_)

Comment: @JoshKelley: Now we need someone to explain why on earth K&R made this decision in the first place :)

Comment: @cyco130: how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7967594/different-between-c-syntax/7967844#7967844 ?

Answer (score 13):

The best answer I've seen as to **why** things like `*` apply to variables and not to types is the idea that [declaration should follow use](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/krnotes/sx8a.html).

Basically, how you *declare* a variable should look similar to how you *use* a variable.

For example,

```
int *a, b;
...
*a = 42;
b = 314159;
```

...the use of `a` and `b` looks similar to the declaration of `a` and `b`.

There's even a citation for this behavior from Dennis Ritchie, one of the creators of C:

> Analogical reasoning led to a declaration syntax for names mirroring that of the expression syntax in which the names typically appear...In all these cases the declaration of a variable resembles its usage in an expression whose type is the one named at the head of the declaration.

- **Dennis Ritchie, [The Development of the C Language](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html)**. *History of Programming Languages-II ed. Thomas J. Bergin, Jr. and Richard G. Gibson, Jr. ACM Press (New York) and Addison-Wesley (Reading, Mass)*, 1996; ISBN 0-201-89502-1.

Comment: Nice argument. But I still think the Pascal way is better: `p: ^Integer;`.

Comment: @cyco130: I don't necessarily agree with 'declaration mimics use', but it (kinda) explains what they were thinking.  :)

Answer (score 7):

The reason is: in reality `&` and `*` in C and C++ applies to variable and no to type.

So the problem is that if you want to declare 4 pointer to integers you should write

```
int *a, *b, *c, *d;
```

Writing `int* a, b;` means

```
int *a;
int b;
```

For this reason a lot of people prefer to write `int *a;` than `int* a;`, just code style.

Of course `int*` is a type, but the C syntax states clearly that in a variable declaration `*` and `&` will apply to variable.

This happens for the same reason that arrays in C are declared in this way:

```
int a[10], b;

std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl; // it will print int[10]
std::cout << typeid(b).name() << std::endl; // it will print int
```

In other languages like C# instead the syntax `int[] array;` is used.

Another thing is the pointer to function syntax:

```
// Now we declare a variable that is a pointer to function
int (*pt2Function)(char, char) = NULL;
```

We are applying the `*` to the variable name.

It seems to me that the use of `*` and `&` applied to the variable, also if 90% of us would prefer differently, is more consistent with the rest of the language.

In the same way, going back to arrays:

```
// Now we declare a variable that is a pointer to an array of 10 integers.
int (*arrayptr)[10];
```

Comment: He seems to know that.  His question is why is it that way?

Comment: Yep. If you really want consistency, you need to use typedef. e.g. `typedef int* intptr; intptr a,b,c,d;`

Comment: Not exactly true, otherwise you couldn't do `typedef int* intptr; intptr a, b, c, d;`

Comment: It is another problem, tenfour, the difference is in just in the syntax, not in the real meaning. Of course int* is a type.

Answer (score 5):

C has a rule for its declarations: Declarations mimic use. What this means is that the declaration for a variable looks like the way the variable is used. For example:

```
int i;
```

Using this variable looks like `i`, and that expression results in an `int`.

```
int *i;
```

Using this variable looks like `*i`, and that expression results in an `int`. This also implies that an expression `i` results in a pointer to an `int`.

```
int i(void);
```

Using this variable looks like `i()`, and results in an `int`. This also implies `i` is a function that takes nothing and that returns an `int`.

```
int (*i[5])();
```

Using this variable looks like `(*i[x])()`, and results in an `int`. This also implies `*i[x]` is a function returning `int`, and `i[x]` is a pointer to a function returning `int`, and `i` is an array of pointers to functions returning `int`.

So:

```
int a, *b, c(void), (*d[5])(void);
```

declares several expressions which all have the type `int`, but the variables themselves are not all `int`s.

N.B. in declarations of function and arrays the sub declarations don't literally resemble the use of the variable. I.e. `int i[5];` doesn't mean that you need to put a '5' inside the square brackets when you use `i`, and `int i(int);` doesn't mean you call the function by saying `i(int);`. Also declarations of variables of struct types don't match their use since you'd have to declare expressions for each member variable.

Related to the syntax for declaring variables is that of typedefs. To declare a typedef with a certain type, you use the same syntax as for declaring a variable of the desired type, but you stick `typedef` in front of the declaration and the variable name becomes the typedef name.

```
typedef int (*array_of_function_pointers[5])(void);
```

C++ adds references, templates, pointers to member, and a bunch of stuff. It tries to some extent to follow the old C convention, but that convention doesn't really work all that well for many of the things C++ adds, so you do start getting inconsistencies. You'll just have to learn the idiosyncrasies and chalk it up to an imperfect marriage between C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

C++ has inherited this syntax from C. The K&R book (§5.1) says that the expression

```
int *ip, **ipp;
```

is intended to be mnemonic (i.e. you read “`*ip` and `**ipp` have type `int`”), they wanted it to mimic usage syntax.

I agree it is quite cryptic and counterintuitive for humans, and inconsistent with typedefs, e.g.

```
typedef int* intptr;
intptr a, b; // equivalent to: int *a, *b
```

but it never really was C++ author's decision, the choice to make the language compatible with C implied using this syntax, that's why.

Comment: I don't see why that's any more inconsistent than any other `typedef`

Comment: good answer. not only this is inconsistent with typedefs but every other places in C++ type system disagrees with qualifiers belonging to the variable. notably function signature : `type+qualif` `functionid` `args`