# Does const/static keyword propagate in variable declaration

Tags: c++

I was wondering whether the const/static keywords apply to all variables declared in a single C++ statement.

For instance, with this code

```
static const int a, b, c;
```

are they all declared as static const ints? Or is just 'a' declared as a static const int and the rest declared as an int or some variation of that?

Comment: Have you tried testing it?

Comment: I have not since I'm on a public computer with no way to code it up.

Comment: [ideone](http://ideone.com)

Comment: @NateRubin, google `Ideone` :)

Comment: Here's an online compiler http://ideone.com/

Comment: One more online compiler from me: http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp_online.php

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Answer (score 8):

`static` and `const` are applied to all variables.

`*`, `[]`, `&` are applied only to a single variable.

E.g.:

```
static int *a, &b=*a, c[10]={};
```

- All variables are static, BUT
- Only `a` is a pointer,
- Only `b` is a reference,
- Only `c` is an array.

For details on variable declaration syntax, see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7967594/2170192) if you're interested *why* the syntax is the way it is.

Comment: I would up-vote this if you supplied a source for your statement.

Comment: @JoshuaD.Boyd: the statement I provided is syntactically correct (it compiles), but it won't run since I initialize a reference by some pointer which points to a random memory location. It produces a segmentation violation or the like. I just wanted to provide a minimal example of the stuff, that's why...

Comment: By a source, I meant in the citation sense (outside authoritative documentation of source sort), not in the supply source code sense.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Everything that could be written left of the actual data type (`int` etc.) modifies that data type and consequently applies to everything declared. Everything else modifies the variable and thus applies only to one variable. But I agree that declarations in C can produce a knot in your brain...

Comment: @JoshuaD.Boyd: oh, that's an excellent point; I've added a few links - though it may not be what you've expected, but this is what I found interesting related to the issue.

Comment: Thanks, thats just the sort of thing I was suggesting.