# using pointers that have ** in c

Tags: c, pointers

I am very new to C and currently having some trouble with pointers and I am not sure if my logic is correct on this question clarification would be great.

Is the second expression legal? Why or Why not? What does it mean?

```
int** x = ....;
... **x ...
```

This is all the question gives and I came up with the following answer (I think its in the ballpark)

The int** x will initialize a pointer x to whatever address/value that is after the equal sign. 
**x ...  will dereference the pointer to a value/variable

The question link that was proposed in the edit was just showing the difference between int* p and int *p which is nothing what i asked i understand this already.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between int\* p and int \*p declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590150/difference-between-int-p-and-int-p-declaration) (yes, I noticed the double-star pointer. It is the same anyway!

Comment: Use cdecl to get the details..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int *x` is a pointer to `int`. `int** y` defines `y` as a pointer to pointer to `int`, so it points to a pointer, and the latter points to an `int`. Example:

```
int n = 42;
int* x = &n; // points to n
int** y = &x; // points to x, which points to n
```

In this case `y` is a pointer to pointer. First indirection `*y` gives you a pointer (in this case `x`), then the second indirection dereferences the pointer `x`, so `**y` equals `42`.

Using `typedef`s makes everything looks simpler, and makes you realize that pointers are themselves variables as any other variables, the only exception being that they store addresses instead of numbers(values):

```
typedef int* pINT;

int n = 42;
pINT x = &n;
pINT* y = &x; // y is a pointer to a type pINT, i.e. pointer to pointer to int
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use double * you are telling the compiler you want a pointer pointing to another pointer:

```
int x = 4;
int *pointer = &x;
int **pointer_pointer = &pointer;
printf("%d\n",**pointer_pointer); // This should print the 4
```